# Yii, I am trying to have a dynamic layout for my views

Tags: php, html, css, yii

I want different views to render using one layout(**sections.php**), but the layout should load a different background for each view. How can i achieve this without using 4 different layouts for each view.

**protected/views/site**

  - index.php
  - about.php
  - product.php
  - brands.php

**protected/views/layout**

  - sections.php

```
<html> 
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div id= "viewname">
       <ul> 
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>about</li>
          <li>products</li>
          <li>brands</li>
       </ul>
       <!--I want to load different bg for this div for each view---> 
       <!--there's a lot of content that comes here, i dont want to do it in every page---> 
       <!--how can i load the class name for this div dynamically if possible-->
      </div>
      <div class=section-cont>
          <?php echo $content; ?>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

my css

```
#about
  {
    .... 
   background-image: ('../img/about.jpg')       
  }
#product
  {
    .... 
   background-image: ('../img/product.jpg')       
  }
#brands
  {
    .... 
   background-image: ('../img/brands.jpg')       
  }
```

myController

```
 class SiteController extends Controller
 {
   public function actionAbout()
   {
    $this->layout = "sections";
    $this->render('about');
   }
  //functions for other views is similar to above
```

Comment: Yii. I Surrender. *_*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you want to change background depending on what page. The way I'd do this is instead of creating a view for each page. Set a variable for in the body tag for the class in your sections layout. Such as:

```
<body class="<?php echo $body_class; ?>">
```

You'll then be able to pass the body class into your view from your Controller Action. Like So:

```
$this->render('about',array('body_class'=> 'about-page'));
```

You'll then be able to target the page and change the background image by targeting the class in your CSS.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT: Question required passing variable to layout**

Sorry - confused myself on layout vs view file.
Layout will have access to `$this` which will be the current controller.
So in your controller if you add a public property/variable land edit the action like so:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public $body_class;
    public function actionTest()
    {
        $this->layout = "testlayout";
        $this->body_class = 'test-page';
        $this->render('test');
    }
```

And then change the body class or div class in the layout file to `$this->body_class`

Note: you could also assign `$this->body_class` in the page view if you prefer it that way.

Comment: i am changing a background of a div instead and that div is only in layout file not the view file, Can you send variables to a layout file?

Comment: @YungA Edited my original comment to answer question for better formatting.

Comment: Wow..thanks alot dude. Your gave the best answer. I never thought layout file has acces to `$this` or current controller

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well your question, you can do it by this. 
1.take current page name.
2.for each page store another value.
3call that class where you want .

```
<?php
$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if($page == 'Home') {
 $css="#Home";
}
if($page == 'about') {
 $css="#about";
}
if($page == 'products') {
  $css="#product"; 
}
if($page == 'brands') {
  $css="#brands";
}
?>
<div  id="<?php echo $css ?>" class="section-cont"> </div>
```